# How do I replace the selected word with another word given in the textfield?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, textfield

I am making a java application in NetBeans, and I would like that the method `replaceAllActionPerformed()`changes the selected text from jTextPane to the text written in jTextField. Should I make that with `getText()` and `setText()` or is there any other way?

Comment: It is hard to say if in your case you should use `getText/setTest` combination, but I suspect that in 90% cases it is right approach.

Comment: @Pshemo: or put the replacement text into the clipboard and call `textField.paste()`.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes, depending on OP circumstances that may also be an option :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like that the method replaceAllActionPerformed()changes the selected text from jTextPane to the text written in jTextField.

```
textPane.replaceSelection( textField.getText() );
```